# Polymorphism, Downcasting, and Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have this code for changing a class to a more Object-Oriented C++ Class, IE: Less calls inside the main loop.

```
class Shape abstract 
{
public:
    virtual bool Check_Collision(SDL_Point);
    virtual bool Check_Collision(SDL_Rect);
    virtual bool Check_Collision(Shape&);
protected:
};

class Adv_Object : public Object
{
public:
    Adv_Object(Shape *obj);
    virtual void Set_Shape(Shape* obj) { prec_area = obj; }
    virtual bool Check_Collision(SDL_Point);
    virtual bool Check_Collision(SDL_Rect);
    virtual bool Check_Collision(Shape&);
protected:
    Shape* prec_area; //Better Area Determination
};
```

Where Shape is a purely abstract class, and is inherited by another class, IE: Circle.

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
  public:
   void Check_Collision(SDL_Point) override;
   void Check_Collision(SDL_Rect) override;
   void Check_Collision(Shape&) override;
};
```

When Circle is downcasted to a Shape, will its overloads of the virtual functions be called or will the abstract functions be called instead?

Comment: Note that `class Shape abstract` isn't C++.

Comment: You have _downcasting_ backward : a Circle is upcast to a Shape.

Comment: @milleniumbug It's C++/CLI extension - OP seems not to know it zzz

Comment: There wouldn't be any point in polymorphism if the virtual functions of a base class were called on an instance of the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program will use run-time information (so-called "virtual table") to determine which virtual function to call. This will be done with a total disregard to your down/up-casting, in other words - the correct overloaded function will be called.

As a side note - if you really want to call a specific "incarnation" of a virtual function then you'd have to use an explicit name resolution, like this:

```
Shape * c = new Circle;
c->Square::Check_Collision(...); // I hope you see the issues this maycause
```